# Creating a relative path

Tags: php

I am creating a require statement where I have a file, public_html/library/register_book.php that **requires** the file public_html/scripts/dial.php

What should the require statement's structure be? I've tried

```
require_once ('../scripts/dial.php');
require_once ('./scripts/dial.php');
require_once ('././scripts/dial.php');
```

etc.
Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: `require_once(__DIR__ . '/../scripts/dial.php');`?

Comment: Consider using `set_include_path` to properly specify the paths you'll require things from. Your second two examples definitely won't work because `.` is the current path. The second two examples actually point to the same place.

Comment: `require_once ('scripts/dial.php');` perhaps? defaults to the root?

Comment: @SamCreamer That gets the `dial.php` in a subfolder of library.

Comment: Set a constant with your base_dir and use it i think.

Comment: If `require_once ('../scripts/dial.php');` didn't work, can you provide any kind of errors from PHP? Based on the structure you provided, `../scripts/` should be correct. Does `dial.php` actually exist?

Comment: @phatskat Yep, dial.php does exist. The error is confusing:-           Warning: require_once(..//dbconnect.php) [function.require-once]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/ptahmeuk/public_html/scripts/dial.php on line 3

Fatal error: require_once() [function.require]: Failed opening required '..//dbconnect.php' (include_path='.:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php') in /home/ptahmeuk/public_html/scripts/dial.php on line 3 dial.php in turn requires a file which is above  public_html. I use dial.php frequently so I know it can find dbconnect.

Comment: Copy and paste the error - confusing or not, we can help a lot more if we can see it.

Comment: Sorry hit return key too soon!

Comment: Which file includes dbconnect.php?

Comment: The parent directory, / ie the file in which public_html resides.  (In theory it should be invisible to anyone visiting the site).

Comment: According to the error message, in line 3 of dial.php should be a `require_once()` statement. Could you post this statement?